# Merging nested list of objects into a single list

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a list of objects, one of which is another list (or actually, Seq[Row] - these are RDDs) and I want to merge them together. There is a list with rows `<a, b, c, d>` where **d** is itself another list `<q, r, s, t>`, one of which is *another* nested list but let's ignore that for simplicity. I want to change this into a list of `<a, b, c, q1, r1, s1, t1>, <a, b, c, q2, r2, s2, t2> ...`

I can extract the information into case classes etc. and then put them together, but I feel there should be a way to use `zip` and `map` etc. to write this in a better functional manner, how should I do so?

*Edit* Detailed description:

The lists are from nested RDD table on hdfs.

```
parent: <Long, String, String, Long, String, Float, Seq[Row] foolist >
foolist: <String, String, Long, Int, Seq[Row] barlist >
barlist: <String, Boolean, Int, Long, Seq[Row] list1, Seq[Row] list2 >
```

They have more fields than stated. Other than the parent object I don't need to filter out any fields in the final result, in which a single row in the parent would become a collection of the values in

```
{parent row}, {foo row 1}, {barlist row 1}
{parent row}, {foo row 1}, {barlist row 2}
{parent row}, {foo row 1}, {barlist row N}
{parent row}, {foo row 2}, {barlist row 1}
{parent row}, {foo row 2}, {barlist row N}
...
{parent row}, {foo row M}, {barlist row N}
```

which are not tuples, just a plain list of fields (Long, String, String, Long, String, Float, String, String, Long, Int, String, Boolean, Int, Long ..)

Comment: I'd suggest putting some actual code into this, ideally some sort of test case. What are the types of the outer and inner lists?

Comment: @AngeloGenovese Done, this data is from a Spark RDD so the list data is Seq[Row]

Comment: It would be much more useful if post actual data and expected output. It still hard to figure out what is going on here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use flatMap for that:

seq.flatMap {case (a,b,c,d) => d.map {case (q,r,s,t) => (a,b,c,q,r,s,t)}}

Or:

```
val res = for {
  (a,b,c,d) <- seq;
  (q,r,s,t) <- d
} yield (a,b,c,q,r,s,t)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
def flat(seq: Seq[Any]):Seq[Any] = seq flatMap {
  case sq:Seq[_] => flat(sq)
  case x => Seq(x)
}
```

**Edit:**
if you want to flatten row, you can try:

```
def flat(seq: Seq[Any]):Seq[Any] = seq flatMap {
  case Seq(row) => flat(row.toSeq)
  case x => Seq(x)
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but I think that flattens the everything into a single list which is not what I want, added more details in the question.